# Django Page Error 404 - Loading JSON via uri

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I am working on a React Frontend - Django rest framework, serving API as backend. When I am loading a model it returns this error 404. I am not sure how I can include the /models in the urls.py so that I am able to load the .json files. Can i use Media_URL or static_URL to serve json files ?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/models/movies.json
Using the URLconf defined in movieproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:


^api/movies/$ [name='movies-list']
^api/movies\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='movies-list']
^api/movies/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='movies-detail']
^api/movies/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='movies-detail']
^$ [name='api-root']
^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
The current path, models/movies.json, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that through your backend code using Django's [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse).

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<file_name>[\w]+).json$', views.loadjson, name='loadjson')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def loadjson(request, file_name):
    json_file = "/path/to/json/" + file_name + ".json"
    json_content = read_file(json_file)
    return HttpResponse(
        json_content,
        content_type='application/json',
        status=200
    )
```

**Note:** Don't forget to edit `/path/to/json/` to your directory path to json files.

This should work fine for you.

Comment: Hi Astik, I am still getting error 404, do I need to include this /models/ folder somewhere in the settings.py ?

Comment: You need to put your json file in `static` directory and then give the path of that directory in the code in views method.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked :) Sorry I didn't have time to work on it. But I tested and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @Arbitel, glad that this helped.